# Warning:: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to connect my react app to a Mongodb database but this happened.

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: This is the first topic on the "[migrating to react 18](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html)" guide.

Answer (score 11):

In React 18, is needed to:

`import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';`

creates your root container with this function:

`const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));`

and then render your root app:

`root.render(<YourApp />);`

you can read this in:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html

Comment: If using TS, add `!` after the root element reference.

Comment: If using TS, add ! after the root element reference to tell typescript *it's never going to be null*.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, just my 2 cents.

Comment: This solution worked for React JS 18 with Laravel & InertiaJs. I researched a lot and finally this solution worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I modified app.jsx to this one >> resources\js\app.jsx >>

createInertiaApp({  
    title: (title) => appName,
    resolve: name => {
        const page = import(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`)
        page.layout = page.layout || Layout
        return page
      },
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        // return render(<App {...props} />, el);
        const root = createRoot(el);
        return root.render(<App {...props} />);
    },
});

Answer (score 4):

Just replace your code with below in index.js file:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: What is the `"root"` meaning ? There's no real `Id` called `"root"`, In React Native I tried to add  `<View nativeID='demo'>` and changed `const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('demo'));`
but that didn't work.